# bindValue with FILE and POST variables into SQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to get all of these variables to post to my database. It works when I leave out the `$_POST` of the `$file_desc`. All of the `$_FILE` variables pass through to my database. Here's the code for grabbing the variables:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = strtolower(end($tmp));
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_error = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$file_desc = nl2br($_POST['desc']);
```

And here's the code for running the query:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, desc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$query->bindValue(1, $file_name);
$query->bindValue(2, $file_ext);
$query->bindValue(3, $file_size);
$query->bindValue(4, $file_desc);

$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is MySQL keyword, which is used to sort selected rows in descending order. In your case MySQL thinks it's keyword and not a field name. To make it understand that it's a field - you should put it in apostrophes:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, `desc`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
```

Also I would advice you to learn debugging and pay attention to errors returned: I bet MySQL told you something about "wrong syntax near desc at line 1".

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly. It's probably best going forward to just change the name of the field. But as a quick fix, that works.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'm a beginner @ this stuff, so I'll try and do that going forward. Though in this case, no error was returned. Nothing was posted.

Comment: Yeah, changing table field in this case seems good. But using apostrophes is common practice to emphasis your table fields, also sometimes you really want keyword to be your field name, e.g. `password`. As for debugging, you can try `print_r($query->errorInfo());` to see your errors.